# VB Row Backcolor resets when sorting table

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I got this code:

```
    Private Sub ColorRows()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If (Not row.IsNewRow) And (row.Cells("Done").Value IsNot DBNull.Value) Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
        End If
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If (Not row.IsNewRow) And (row.Cells("Note").Value IsNot DBNull.Value) And (row.Cells("Done").Value Is DBNull.Value) Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But when I want to sort column, it resets back to white - so I can't for example sort by Done column, to see Green (Done) rows together and notDone rows together.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call `ColorRows`? Is `DataGridView1` bound?

Comment: @Steeeve ColorRows() is in Form load after columns create. I don't know what does it mean if it's bound.

Comment: How do you fill the datagridview? Try to subscribe the [Sorted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) event and call `ColorRows` from the event handler.

Comment: @Steeeve I do all things from guides, I'm doing it just for one program, so I absolutely don't know how, your link leads to C# If I see it right, I use only VB. I fill it via textboxes and dropdown.

Comment: You can switch to VB with the `</>` button in the documentation I linked.

Comment: I would recommend to override the [RowPostPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint?view=netframework-4.8) event for example. [Here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/painting-on-the-datagridview/) is an example in both VB.net & C# to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to sort the row by clicking on the sort features in dgv. Also while sorting you want to retain the colour definition base on the value of a column cell.
i.e. if the value is Done then Green, if value is Note then white

Assume your dgv name is dgvResult
here is the code 
The mouse click event that call the sorting

```
Private Sub dgvResult_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles   
dgvResult.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Sort()
End Sub
```

The code to do the background colour

```
Private Sub Sort()

        For i = 0 To dgvResult.RowCount - 1

            With dgvResult
                If .Item(0, i).Value = "Done" Then
                    .Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
                End If

                If .Item(0, i).Value = "Note" Then
                    .Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
                End If
            End With

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why name the Sub "Sort" when the code doesn't sort anything?

Comment: That is not for sorting. That is to show the colour. The VB itself has already a sort feature when u click on the column header.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. The function could be named `OnSort()` or `SetCellBackColor`.

Comment: It was just an example and you could name it whatever you want.